# Jetapck Compose : After Updating Compose BOM to latest version "2024.01.00" CircularProgressIndicator Give Error

Tags: android, kotlin, animation, android-jetpack-compose

Recently In one of my project updated to latest Compose Version to 2024.01.00 and it's giving me the following error.

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No virtual method at(Ljava/lang/Object;I)Landroidx/compose/animation/core/KeyframesSpec$KeyframeEntity; in class Landroidx/compose/animation/core/KeyframesSpec$KeyframesSpecConfig; or its super classes (declaration of 'androidx.compose.animation.core.KeyframesSpec$KeyframesSpecConfig' appears in /data/app/~~Sbx7baz2GwMCcVZ6x7z-CA==/com.ai.aso.wallpaper-PqJGZgl7MXHWAf_XL7CGuA==/base.apk)
                                                                                                        at androidx.compose.material3.ProgressIndicatorKt$CircularProgressIndicator$endAngle$1.invoke(ProgressIndicator.kt:371)
                                                                                                        at androidx.compose.material3.ProgressIndicatorKt$CircularProgressIndicator$endAngle$1.invoke(ProgressIndicator.kt:369)
                                                                                                        at androidx.compose.animation.core.AnimationSpecKt.keyframes(AnimationSpec.kt:649)
                                                                                                        at androidx.compose.material3.ProgressIndicatorKt.CircularProgressIndicator-LxG7B9w(ProgressIndicator.kt:369)
                                                                                                        at com.ai.aso.wallpaper.presentation.screens.browse.BrowseScreenKt.BrowseScreen(BrowseScreen.kt:159)
                                                                                                        at com.ai.aso.wallpaper.presentation.screens.home.HomeScreenKt$HomeScreen$3$3$1$1.invoke(HomeScreen.kt:161)
                                                                                                        at com.ai.aso.wallpaper.presentation.screens.home.HomeScreenKt$HomeScreen$3$3$1$1.invoke(HomeScreen.kt:158)
                                                                                                        at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:139)
                                                                                                        at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:35)
                                                                                                        at androidx.compose.foundation.pager.PagerLazyLayoutItemProvider$Item$1.invoke(LazyLayoutPager.kt:199)
                                                                                                        at androidx.compose.foundation.pager.PagerLazyLayoutItemProvider$Item$1.invoke(LazyLayoutPager.kt:197)
                                                                                                        at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:109)
                                                                                                        at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:35)
                                                                                                        at androidx.compose.runtime.CompositionLocalKt.CompositionLocalProvider(CompositionLocal.kt:248)
                                                                                                        at androidx.compose.foundation.lazy.layout.LazyLayoutPinnableItemKt.LazyLayoutPinnableItem(LazyLayoutPinnableItem.kt:58)
                                                                                                        at androidx.compose.foundation.pager.PagerLazyLayoutItemProvider.Item(LazyLayoutPager.kt:197)
                                                                                                        at androidx.compose.foundation.lazy.layout.LazyLayoutItemContentFactoryKt$SkippableItem$1.invoke(LazyLayoutItemContentFactory.kt:135)
                                                                                                        at androidx.compose.foundation.lazy.layout.LazyLayoutItemContentFactoryKt$SkippableItem$1.invoke(LazyLayoutItemContentFactory.kt:134)
                                                                                                        at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:109)
                                                                                                        at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:35)
                                                                                                        at androidx.compose.runtime.CompositionLocalKt.CompositionLocalProvider(CompositionLocal.kt:248)
                                                                                                        at androidx.compose.runtime.saveable.SaveableStateHolderImpl.SaveableStateProvider(SaveableStateHolder.kt:84)
                                                                                                        at androidx.compose.foundation.lazy.layout.LazySaveableStateHolder.SaveableStateProvider(LazySaveableStateHolder.kt:85)
                                                                                                        at androidx.compose.foundation.lazy.layout.LazyLayoutItemContentFactoryKt.SkippableItem-JVlU9Rs(LazyLayoutItemContentFactory.kt:134)
                                                                                                        at androidx.compose.foundation.lazy.layout.LazyLayoutItemContentFactoryKt.access$SkippableItem-JVlU9Rs(LazyLayoutItemContentFactory.kt:1)
                                                                                                        at androidx.compose.foundation.lazy.layout.LazyLayoutItemContentFactory$CachedItemContent$createContentLambda$1.invoke(LazyLayoutItemContentFactory.kt:101)
                                                                                                        at androidx.compose.foundation.lazy.layout.LazyLayoutItemContentFactory$CachedItemContent$createContentLambda$1.invoke(LazyLayoutItemContentFactory.kt:91)
                                                                                                        at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:109)
                                                                                                        at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:35)
                                                                                                        at androidx.compose.ui.layout.LayoutNodeSubcompositionsState$subcompose$3$1$1.invoke(SubcomposeLayout.kt:989)
                                                                                                        at androidx.compose.ui.layout.LayoutNodeSubcompositionsState$subcompose$3$1$1.invoke(SubcomposeLayout.kt:476)
2024-01-26 16:05:55.828  8297-8297  AndroidRuntime          com.ai.aso.wallpaper                 E      at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:109)
                                                                                                        at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:35)
                                                                                                        at androidx.compose.runtime.ActualJvm_jvmKt.invokeComposable(ActualJvm.jvm.kt:90)
                                                                                                        at androidx.compose.runtime.ComposerImpl.doCompose(Composer.kt:3302)
                                                                                                        at androidx.compose.runtime.ComposerImpl.composeContent$runtime_release(Composer.kt:3235)
                                                                                                        at androidx.compose.runtime.CompositionImpl.composeContent(Composition.kt:723)
                                                                                                        at androidx.compose.runtime.Recomposer.composeInitial$runtime_release(Recomposer.kt:1071)
                                                                                                        at androidx.compose.runtime.ComposerImpl$CompositionContextImpl.composeInitial$runtime_release(Composer.kt:3599)
                                                                                                        at androidx.compose.runtime.ComposerImpl$CompositionContextImpl.composeInitial$runtime_release(Composer.kt:3599)
                                                                                                        at androidx.compose.runtime.CompositionImpl.composeInitial(Composition.kt:631)
                                                                                                        at androidx.compose.runtime.CompositionImpl.setContent(Composition.kt:617)
                                                                                                        at androidx.compose.ui.layout.LayoutNodeSubcompositionsState.subcomposeInto(SubcomposeLayout.kt:499)
                                                                                                        at androidx.compose.ui.layout.LayoutNodeSubcompositionsState.subcompose(SubcomposeLayout.kt:471)
                                                                                                        at androidx.compose.ui.layout.LayoutNodeSubcompositionsState.subcompose(SubcomposeLayout.kt:462)
                                                                                                        at androidx.compose.ui.layout.LayoutNodeSubcompositionsState.subcompose(SubcomposeLayout.kt:446)
                                                                                                        at androidx.compose.ui.layout.LayoutNodeSubcompositionsState$Scope.subcompose(SubcomposeLayout.kt:871)
                                                                                                        at androidx.compose.foundation.lazy.layout.LazyLayoutMeasureScopeImpl.measure-0kLqBqw(LazyLayoutMeasureScope.kt:125)
                                                                                                        at androidx.compose.foundation.pager.PagerMeasureKt.getAndMeasure-SGf7dI0(PagerMeasure.kt:522)
                                                                                                        at androidx.compose.foundation.pager.PagerMeasureKt.measurePager-_JDW0YA(PagerMeasure.kt:203)
                                                                                                        at androidx.compose.foundation.pager.PagerMeasurePolicyKt$rememberPagerMeasurePolicy$1$1.invoke-0kLqBqw(PagerMeasurePolicy.kt:159)
                                                                                                        at androidx.compose.foundation.pager.PagerMeasurePolicyKt$rememberPagerMeasurePolicy$1$1.invoke(PagerMeasurePolicy.kt:69)
                                                                                                        at androidx.compose.foundation.lazy.layout.LazyLayoutKt$LazyLayout$3$2$1.invoke-0kLqBqw(LazyLayout.kt:107)
                                                                                                        at androidx.compose.foundation.lazy.layout.LazyLayoutKt$LazyLayout$3$2$1.invoke(LazyLayout.kt:100)
                                                                                                        at androidx.compose.ui.layout.LayoutNodeSubcompositionsState$createMeasurePolicy$1.measure-3p2s80s(SubcomposeLayout.kt:708)
                                                                                                        at androidx.compose.ui.node.InnerNodeCoordinator.measure-BRTryo0(InnerNodeCoordinator.kt:126)
                                                                                                        at androidx.compose.foundation.AndroidOverscroll_androidKt$StretchOverscrollNonClippingLayer$2.invoke-3p2s80s(AndroidOverscroll.android.kt:584)
                                                                                                        at androidx.compose.foundation.AndroidOverscroll_androidKt$StretchOverscrollNonClippingLayer$2.invoke(AndroidOverscroll.android.kt:583)
```

Comment: Use the latest RC version of Material3, which has the fixe for this issue. 
https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/compose-material3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Issue on Google Issue tracker
https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/322214617

Fix provided by compose team
https://android-review.googlesource.com/c/platform/frameworks/support/+/2928171

Use Below Material3 Version For now

```
androidx.compose.material3:material3-*:1.2.0-rc01
```

Comment: I hope they do a better job with upcoming releases of the material library for compose.

Comment: Yes, You are right

Answer (score 0):

It's fixed on `2024.02.00`.
[androidx.compose.animation:animation-*:1.6.1](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/compose-animation#1.6.1)